# Create (bootable) image of external hard drive

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive, disk-image

I have a loose (external) hard drive with Windows 10 installed on it, mounted with a drive letter K: in Winows 10 via USB.

How can I create an (ideally) bootable image or a bootable USB stick from that drive without having to boot from it first?

I.e. similar as creating a bootable USB stick from the currently running Windows, for example using [WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) or the like -- however from that "offline", external Windows hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found two ways to do it:

1. [Disk2vhd](https://superuser.com/questions/337607/software-that-can-make-a-mountable-image-of-my-hard-drive)
2. [WinCDEmu](https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/tutorials/create/)

I tried the first one, and it worked instantly.